# Python class inheritance issue occurs when using base class to assign attributes of subclass

Tags: python, inheritance

When using base class to create sub class attribute, I got an error that sub class has no member which I created in the base class method. Codes are shown below

```
class Base(object):
    def setAttributes(self, data):
        for key in data:
            self.key = data[key]

class Sub(Base):
    pass

data = {'id':1, 'name': 'Name'}
a = Sub()
Base.setAttributes(a, data)

print(a.id)
```

And the error messages are : **AttributeError: 'Sub' object has no attribute 'id'.**

Is there any solution to use base class to assign sub class attributes in python?

Comment: Use `print(a.__dict__)` to see what is actually being set (as kindall pointed out).  Also `a.setAttributes(data)` is the usual way using a method like this (though the effect is the same).

Comment: I can see something using a.__dict__, there just only key in a. I know how to do it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with inheritance. You have assigned the value to `a.key` not `a.id`. In fact you have assigned *all* your values to `a.key`.

I believe you want `setattr(self, key, data[key])` in place of `self.key = data[key]`. Or just do away with the loop entirely and do `self.__dict__.update(data)`.